# Get random word of specific length from wordlist

Tags: php, file, random, strlen, word-list

I am writing a simple PHP function that will access word-list.txt and pull a random word (the words are separated by a new line). This word needs to have a maximum length of $maxlength. The way that I have written it, it will pull the word and if the length is too long, then it will keep getting a new word until it is less than or equal to $maxlength. The issue that I am running into is that the script returns a fatal error for a maximum execution time. Here is the code:

```
function GetWord($maxlength) {
    $file_content = file('word-list.txt');
    $nword = $file_content[array_rand($file_content)];

    while(mb_strlen($nword) > $maxlength) {
        $nword = $file_content[array_rand($file_content)];
    }

    return $nword;
}
```

The only alternative that I could think of is putting the wordlist into a database and having a column with each corresponding word's length. That would allow me to select the word choices based on their length. I am trying to avoid having to use a database however, so I want to find out what is wrong with my script. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Something I should have mentioned is that this file is rather large and contains over 9,000 lines. This is causing some of the given suggestions to still timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following class does some sorting when instantiated, but then every lookup for a random word takes only O(1) time:

```
class RandomWord {
    private $words;
    private $boundaries;

    private static function sort($a, $b){
        return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
    }

    function __construct($file_name) {
        $this->words = file($file_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

        // Sort the words by their lenghts
        usort($this->words, array('RandomWord', 'sort'));

        // Mark the length boundaries
        $last = strlen($this->words[0]);

        foreach($this->words as $key => $word) {
            $length = strlen($word);

            if ($length > $last) {
                for($i = $last; $i < $length; $i++) {
                    // In case the lengths are not continuous
                    //    we need to mark the intermediate values as well
                    $this->boundaries[$i] = $key - 1;
                }
                $last = $length;
            }
        }
    }

    public function get($max_length) {
        if (isset($this->boundaries[$max_length])) {
            return $this->words[rand(0, $this->boundaries[$max_length])];
        }

        return $this->words[array_rand($this->words)];
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
$r = new RandomWord("word-list.txt");
$word1 = $r->get(6);
$word2 = $r->get(3);
$word3 = $r->get(7);
...
```

Update: now I have tested it and works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from overly complicating things.

You could explode the content

```
$content_array = explode("\n", $file_content);
```

Shuffle the array

```
shuffle($content_array)
```

And then search for the first word of the given length.

```
foreach($content_array as $word) {
    if(strlen($word) == $word_length)
        return $word;
}
```

I would personally put everything in a database though.

Answer (score 0):

Retrying with random indexes is indeed rather inefficient.

You could filter the lines by the length condition, so that you only have the valid lines left over, and then flip those lines, so they become keys. Then `array_rand` can be used to pick a random key from those. All of this can be done in a *functional programming* way:

```
function GetWord($maxlength) {
    return array_rand(array_flip(array_filter(file('word-list.txt'), 
        function($line) use ($maxlength) {
            return mb_strlen($line) <= $maxlength;
        })));
}
```